# Can I set the background image the property(Scale to Fill, Aspect Fit, Aspect Fill)？

Tags: html, css, image

In html can I set the background image the below property？(the image is in iOS I can set the image's fill property like below, but I don't know if there is the similar property in html):

```
Scale to Fill,
Aspect Fit,
Aspect Fill
```

[image]

In my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>

        #div1 {
            width:300px;
            height:200px;
            background: gray url(img/1.png);

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The image is like this:

[image]

But the result is like below, the image is trim:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size?v=control

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first three properties that would be:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: contain;
background-size: cover;
```

And this would be the code to recreate the Ford image you're showing with the three background size properties.

```css
#img1,#img2,#img3{
  background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Ford_Motor_Company_Logo.svg/2000px-Ford_Motor_Company_Logo.svg.png);
  background-position:center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color:#f00;
  width:20vw;
  height:20vw;
  display:inline-block;
}
#img1{background-size:100% 100%}
#img2{background-size:contain}
#img3{background-size:cover}
```

```html
<div id="img1"></div>
<div id="img2"></div>
<div id="img3"></div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhuhkam5/1/).

For your second question the best solution would be to use background-size:cover; like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        #div1 {
            width:300px;
            height:200px;
            background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOnF7.png);
            background-size:cover;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you have additional questions, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

For a background image, your  "Aspect Fit" equals `background-size: contain;`, `Aspect Fill` would be `cover`